# Rails - Ajax, how can I update cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my order items, I can remove a line, it fades out with ajax

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$(".delete_btn").bind('ajax:success', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
     //I tried the code below
     //$("#item_count").html("<%= current_cart.items_count %>")
})
```

When it's deleted, I want Ajax to update:

- the cart items (it is in the navbar)

  `<span id="items_count"><%= current_cart.items_count %></span>`
- the total price (in the order_items/index)

  `<td colspan='4' align="right"><%= number_to_currency_euro current_cart.sub_total %></td>`

EDIT:

My question is: what code I am supposed to write in ajax, to update the total price and the items number with Ajax?

`current_cart` is defined application controller

```
before_action :current_cart

  def current_cart
    @current_cart ||= ShoppingCart.new(token: cart_token)
  end

private

 def cart_token
   return @cart_token unless @cart_token.nil?
   session[:cart_token] ||= SecureRandom.hex(8)
   @cart_token = session[:cart_token]
 end
```

order_items_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
    current_cart.remove_item(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to clients_cart_path, notice: "Correctement supprimé du panier" }
    end   
  end
```

Comment: And what is your question? Did you try to write some code to achieve what you want?

Comment: The question is how do I update the item numbers and the price with Ajax  (Sorry if my question is not very clear)... I tried this  line `$("#item_count").html("<%= current_cart.items_count %>");`in my function  but I am on the wrong way, so I did not put it in the question

Comment: What is `current_cart`? Did you define it in delete action? Is it accessible in `destroy.js.erb` (you can check it with `console.log(<%= current_cart.items_count %>`)?

Comment: `console.log(<%= current_cart.items_count %>`doesn't work in my console browser

Comment: I suppose js views has no access to helpers. Try to use instance variable @current_cart in `destroy.js.erb`. BTW, helper is not the best place for defining @variables, it would be better to move the method to `before_action` in a controller (maybe in ApplicationController, if you need the cart across the whole app)

Comment: I moved current_cart method in application controller and made a before action. also added @ in the destroy action.  But, how I am supposed to write the ajax code to update the quantity ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".delete_btn").bind('ajax:success', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
    $("#items_count").html("<%= @current_cart.items_count %>");
    $("#total_amount").html("<%= number_to_currency_euro @current_cart.sub_total %>");
});
```

That's the code I finally wrote and that works well... I renamed my #id and found out that there was a typo...

Comment: Great! Happy, that you've found the answer!